# React with Material-UI Drawer and AppBar components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I am using the material-ui AppBar and the Drawer component. As you can see from my project structure every component has his own file. I can't find any documentation to trigger the Temporary drawer Button the the Menu "OPEN LEFT"-Button.

1. **Temporary drawer:** https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/
2. **App Bar with a primary search field:** https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/

**Project Structure:**

```
App/
  App.js
Menu/
  Menu.js
Navigation/
  Navigation.js
```

Comment: just asking, you aren't able to open the drawer when pressing the home button, thats the issue? 

if so, you won't find that in any documentation because it seems that you may be lacking React knowledge.

What you need to do is to store a state value (holding open/close state of the drawer) and then just toggle that value with the menu button, and set the "open" prop of the drawer to that state value.

I can give you a further hand if thats the case :) but I recommend you to read the basic usage of react if this is the case !

Comment: @LinoRabolini Yes i am currently learning it :) That would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find any documentation for that ... just add left menu on click of the icon button in AppBar.
If you want i can share the whole code as I have worked upon this.

**Update**:-

Here is the code or your reference with Both components in seperate file's 
https://codesandbox.io/s/38wm039565

Do Let me know if I this was something you were looking for.

Let me know if you need any further support on this.

Cheers !!

Comment: Yes, please. Cool! :D

Comment: Nice example, but the Drawer and the AppBar are still in the same file and not component based in my opinion.

Comment: Yes,Drawer and App Bar were in the same file .. Now i have separated both the components in separate files .. Have a look at code.